# Make 50unattended-upgrades writable

Tags: 18.04, updates, security

I'm trying to follow this guide to setup automatic security updates to my server:
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-setup-automatic-security-updates-on-ubuntu-1604/

I'm at step 2 and trying to update the 50unattended-upgrades but this file is unwriteable. How can I make this file writeable so I can update it based on the guide?

Comment: That is an awful tutorial, likely to cause more problems than it solves. Unattended Upgrades is already installed in Ubuntu 16.04, already enabled (unless you disabled it), and already set up for security upgrades only. All that most 16.04 users need to do is to turn it back on using the Software & Updates control panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial is written expecting you to be using the `root` user which is by-default locked.  Run the `vim` command it specifies with `sudo` - `sudo vim 50unattended-upgrades`.  You'll need to do similar with other "edit files" commands.